# Google Script - Setvalues() not fetching the desired result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch all the files' link (spreadsheet link) added in a specific google drive folder. However, while running the below code, even though I am able to get the desired output in Logger, it's not getting added to the google sheet using setvalues() function. The issue is not any error, but it's returning only one file name and that does not help. Not really sure of a way to crack this, would really appreciate all your help in this!

```
  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERPATH");

  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();

  var file;
  var fileType;
  var ssID;
  var data;
  
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      Logger.log(ssID);
      
      
    }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1).setValues([[ssID]]);  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] currently getDataFromSpreadsheet is undefined

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERPATH");

  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();

  var file;
  var fileType;
  var ssID;
  var data;

  const ids = [];
  
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      Logger.log(ssID);
      ids.push(ssID)
    }
  }

  const inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                   .getSheetByName("Input")

  const currentValues = inputSheet.getRange(`A2:A`)
                                  .getDisplayValues()
                                  .flat()
                                  .filter(String)

  const updatedValues = [... new Set([...currentValues, ...ids])].map(i => [i])

  inputSheet.getRange(`A2:A`).clearContent()
  inputSheet.getRange(2, 1, ids.length, ids[0].length)
            .setValues(updatedValues)
```

Because you said your script is running correctly through logging, I'm assuming `var range = sheet.getRange(2,1).setValues([[ssID]]);` is overwriting the value in the `A2` cell repeatedly.

**See:**

- [.appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Running this code gives me an error saying "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow." Any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had corrected that. Try the updated code!

Comment: Yup this works!! Only issue is that the output is getting placed at the last rows in column A. I tried adding a getrange to the above code , but guess appendrow does not work with it. Anyways, gets the job done. thanks!

Comment: Ok, one more update! It will now look for the first blank space in Column A and insert all IDs. If you plan to rewrite over these versus append them, let me know.

Comment: yeah I observed that when I rerun it again, it's getting duplicated.. so currently I placed a 'UNIQUE' formula in column B and base all my workings on that.. If there's a way to not append the same list over and over again and give me a unique list everytime I run the code, that would be great. (PS: currently I have the column A as blank and still it goes to the last row to paste the output)

Comment: @Vish Updated once again. This time it will input all unique starting at A2 (hypothetically).

Comment: this works well! just had to delete "data=getdatafromspreadsheet(ssID)" and add [] to "ids.push([ssID])" from the code.. Also, noted that this code does not work when I run it for the second time when a new file is added to the folder.. Column A has to be blank to be able to return the output. Gives me the error: "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 26 but the range has 13." Would you suggest adding another macro to clear contents in column A before running the code? or use the previous one?

Comment: Why did you change to `ids.push([ssID])`? It should work correctly without it. You will need to clear the range before inserting only if there is less files/ids than before, however, I've added it to the code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get all data for all spreadsheets in a folder

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDERPATH");
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      ssID = file.getId();
      let tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue(tss.getName());
      tss.getSheets().forEach(s => {
        let vs = s.getDataRange().getValues();
        sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(s.getName());
        sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code is not returning any data for me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It put's it into a sheet named "Input".  All of the files are in the folder.  Did you add the folder id?

Comment: yes I did.. the code works and it's not returning any error. However, there is no output. Not sure of the reason. I copied the above script directly and made change only to the folderpath..

Comment: Hey Cooper! - Apologies.. The code works very well! Just now noticed that the output is getting placed towards the last rows, that's why couldn't find it before.. Although, this is not the output I wanted, I was looking to fetch only the spreadsheet links for the files placed in a specific drive folder. This obviously will come handy for other areas I am working on. Thanks much!